# Can someone please explain what is the use of 32 in this remove spaces from string method? java

Tags: java, for-loop, charat

public static String RemoveSpace(String s){
String str="";

```
  for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
     if(s.charAt(i)!=32)
        str+=s.charAt(i);
    
  return str.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: 32 is the ASCII code for a space character. It is the same as saying  `!= ' '`

Comment: Well, yes, but Java doesn't use ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is just a number - a numeric type with two bytes.  It's often written inside `''` marks, but it can be used interchangeably with other numbers.  In particular, the value of `' '` (space) is `32`, when considered as a number.  So when you compare a `char` with `32`, you're just comparing it to `' '`, even though `32` is technically four bytes, not just two.

Your code example just appends characters to `str` whenever they are NOT the same as 32, in other words, when they're not spaces.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php

In the ASCII table 32 stands for Space.